# Sending a post method to server undefined - error

Tags: node.js, express, pug

My form is in `JADE` and it look like this.

```
  form(action='/test/about', method='post')
          .form-group
            label(for='nameFormControlInput1') Name
            input#nameFormControlInput1.form-control(type='text', placeholder='name')
  .form-group
          input(type='submit', value='Add')
```

In my `app.js` I have a `POST` method defined as follows:

```
var express = require('express')
  , stylus = require('stylus')
  , nib = require('nib')


var app = express()

function compile(str, path) {
  return stylus(str)
    .set('filename', path)
    .use(nib());
}

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
app.set('view engine', 'jade')
app.use(express.logger('dev'))
app.use(stylus.middleware(
  { src: __dirname + '/public'
  , compile: compile
  }
))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index',
  { title : 'Home' }
  )
})

app.post('/test/about', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.render('index',
  { title : 'Home' }
  )
})

app.listen(3000)
```

However, I have added console.log(req.body) and It now prints as undefined
How can I solve this ?

Comment: can you show the error you are getting?

Comment: Well, I just ran it again, and I don't see the server 500 anymore. (newbie) Anyhow, I have added `console.log(req.body)` and It now prints as `undefined`. Help. I have updated my post above with the code

Comment: What is your purpose ? dou you want to get posted data ? waht kind of response do you want to return ?

Comment: I want to get the Data send from the Form and send it as a response to the index.jade page for now. Later I will save it on to a DB. but for now, I need to take the data that was passed from the form and send it back to index.jade

Comment: It's because you are not using body-parser, http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html#bodyparserurlencodedoptions

Comment: If you post your form as urlencoded, you need [bodyParser.urlencoded](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body) to get the values in the body.

Answer (score 0):

Ok first of all you need to add name attribute to your input element and use the [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)

```
    var express = require('express')
        , stylus = require('stylus')
        , nib = require('nib')
        , bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    var app = express()
    function compile(str, path) {
        return stylus(str)
            .set('filename', path)
            .use(nib());
    }

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

   app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
   app.set('view engine', 'jade')
    // app.use(express.logger('dev'))
    app.use(stylus.middleware(
        {
            src: __dirname + '/public'
            , compile: compile
        }
    ))
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.render('index',
            { title: 'Home' }
        )
    })

    app.post('/test/about', function (req, res) {
        console.log(req.body);

        res.render('formresult',
            {
                title: 'Form Result',
                name: req.body.nameFormControlInput1
            }
        )
    })

    app.listen(3000)
```

after data posted, you can acces it using `req.body.nameFormControlInput1`

And I create a another jade file to display posted data.

**formresult.jade**

```
- if(name)
 h1=name
- else
 h1 No data
```

**index.jade**

add `name="nameFormControlInput1"` to input field

```
form(action='/test/about', method='post')
 .form-group
  label(for='nameFormControlInput1') Name
  input#nameFormControlInput1.form-control(type='text', placeholder='name', name="nameFormControlInput1")
  .form-group
   input(type='submit', value='Add')
```

Comment: instead of displaying text from `formresult`, I changed that to `index` instead hoping it'll display the data on my Index. I also pasted the code found in your `formresult ` on the index page. But, it doesn't get displayed. It always says No Data

Comment: @Illep  If you want to show data in index, you need to post data to index page. So, change the form action to  `'/'` and change  `app.post('/test/about' ,..` to `app.post('/',..` . Also when you render index page send form data too.

Comment: How do I show it in the `index.jade` page. `#{title}`did not work.